# Dynamically addSeries highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I had a problem in adding series dynamically with highstock. Inorder to do this, I'm using the chart.addSeries function. The first series also should be added dynamically via data comming from a web service. My problem is in the first view of my chart. I mean when the chart is first shown the scrollbar is not shown properly, but when I click on the ZOOM area(1,3,6 month - yearly - ytd) the scrollbar appears.

```
chart.addSeries({
                name: name,
                data: data,
                type: 'spline'
            });
```

also I'm setting data to navigator separately(inorder to have data on xAxis properly) and **the series property is empty(at first I don't have any series)- The problem is here(empty series)**

I have seen a lot of examples with addSeries to other series, but haven't seen as the first series.

```
 var navigator = chart.get('navigator');
            navigator.setData(data);
```

I have searched a lot, but I could'nt find a good solution.Please help me...

Thank you

Comment: Show us some demo, how to reproduce this issue.

Comment: for example like this  http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/members/chart-addseries/ but the difference is that my series is empty at first and the first series is being applied dynamically like all other series, in the addSeries api reference has been said that the **base series** with **navigator enabled** can't be added dynamically.

Comment: Another thing: I can use multiple series to achieve my goal but I wanted to do it with addSeries to have a light code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with selected button in range selector. You force Highstock to set extremes on empty data, so it will produce error. What you can to is to set directly extremes after data is added, see:

```
chart.addSeries({
        name: 'ADBE',
        data: ADBE
    }, false);
    var nav = chart.get('navigator');
    nav.setData(ADBE);
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(); //reset or set extremes to get navigator and scrollbar
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/vqa2r/